# How to control a servo motor using servo library in C++ on Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

I try to rotate a full rotation servo motor using the [Arduino Pro](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardPro) kit. I’m using the servo library and especially the function servo. I use `Write()` in order to control the speed and the direction of the servo motor using this function.

According to the Arduino C++ servo library, the parameter for the write function is the angle in the standard servo, and the speed for the full rotation servo. Now I want to know the unit of this parameter, because when I set this parameter to 45 the speed is higher than when I set it to 90! How can I fix this problem?

Comment: it is in degrees as stated in http://playground.arduino.cc/ComponentLib/servo

Answer (score 4):

> On a continuous rotation servo, this will set the speed of the servo
>   (with 0 being full-speed in one direction, 180 being full speed in the
>   other, and a value near 90 being no movement).

Source: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServoWrite

Comment: @IbrahimAbdulhaq since it is a rotation and  we are looking for the speed it should be the "angular velocity" as described in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity

Comment: @IbrahimAbdulhaq **MarkusDeibel is not true.** Since continuous rotation servos have no feedback mechanism, they can't control speed. Continuous rotation servos are real servos with resistors instead of the potentiometer so it is tricked to think that the servo is at 90 degrees. When you do 91, it goes slower than set at 180 because it knows it is closer so it doesn't go as fast. There is no speed, the degree is the ratio of the amount of speed that the motor in can provide. (see this for information on how servos work: http://www.servocity.com/html/how_do_servos_work_.html).

Comment: **More information if the post above didn't make sense:** http://www.pololu.com/blog/24/continuous-rotation-servos-and-multi-turn-servos ** Additional note:** A servo set at the speed of 45/90 degrees (Arduino tells it either 45 or 135 depending on the direction) it won't necessarily go 1/2 the speed of 90/90 degrees (Arduino tells the servo 0 or 180).

Answer (score 0):

I have some code example for controlling servo motors from class library, i hope you can get a little help form it.

go to:http://everysolutionshere.blogspot.in/2013/05/step-to-control-servo-motors-from-c.html

You can uses a axis card to control servo easily. It provides the better accuracy for pulse and direction controlling.

Comment: Hello and welcome!  I'm not sure that what you've posted directly answers the question posed.  If some of the example code on your link answers the question, please extract the relevant bits and put them in your answer.  SO tends to discorage link only answers.